# Append path to icon - Google Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In my project I'm binding a list of 'paper-fab' elements from a JSON array. 
I want to give only the name of the icon instead of the full path to bind with 'src' property of 'paper-fab'. How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do it with computed property? Thanks in advance.

The code snippet and JSON format is given below.

```
<ul id="actionButtons">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[plugins]]">
        <li>
            <span>
                <paper-fab mini src="[[item.iconSrc]]" id="[[item.id]]" name="[[item.name]]" class$="[[item.cssClass]]"> </paper-fab>
            </span>
        </li>
    </template> </ul>
```

**JSON structure is given below**

```
plugins:
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Image_1",
            "iconSrc": "app/images/icons/pacs_pull.png",
            "cssClass": "white"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Image_2",
            "iconSrc": "app/images/icons/pacs_push.png",
            "cssClass": "grey"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Image_3",
            "iconSrc": "app/images/icons/fileBrowser.png",
            "cssClass": "white",
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Computed bindings](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)

```
  <template>
    My name is <span>{{computeFullName(first, last)}}</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-custom',
      properties: {
        first: String,
        last: String       
      },
      computeFullName: function(first, last) {
        return first + ' ' + last;
      }
      ...
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

You should be able to pass `item.iconSrc` to you compute to append the path to the icon

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked!. I checked 'Computed Binding' option earlier, but I couldn't figure out how to pass parameter.